# backbone.js el exists but does not show content

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

i'm stuck for a few hours with the  `el` property of a view.
I'm using Marionette.js but it's the same logic, i guess..

Anyways what i do is: create a layout view and add a sidebar to it: (everything is requested via require.js)

```
                    var applicationLayout = new ApplicationLayout();

                this.regions.main.show(applicationLayout);
                applicationLayout.sidebar.show(new ApplicationSidebarView({appId:id}));
```

ApplicationLayout.js

```
define
(
    ['marionette', 'tpl!templates/dashboard/application/ApplicationLayout.tpl'],
    function (Marionette, tpl)
    {
        "use strict";

        return Marionette.Layout.extend
        (
            {
                template: tpl,
                className: 'row',

                regions: 
                {
                    sidebar: '#application-nav',
                    detail: '#application-detail'
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

ApplicationLayout.tpl : i see this in the inspector -> layout is rendered correctly

```
<div class="span2">
    <nav id="application-nav">
    </nav>
</div>
```

ApplicationSidebarView:

```
define
(
    ['marionette', 'jquery', 'tpl!templates/dashboard/application/ApplicationSidebar.tpl'],
    function (Marionette, $, tpl)
    {
        "use strict";

        return Marionette.ItemView.extend
        (
            {
                template: tpl,
                //el : "#application-nav", // commented out works fine

                initialize : function()
                {
                    this.appId = this.options.appId;
                    console.log('init');
                },

                render : function()
                {
                    console.log(this.$el); // returns the $ object
                    var html = tpl({'appId': this.appId});
                    console.log(html);  // returns the compiled template correct
                    console.log($('#application-detail').length) // 1
                    $('#application-detail').html(html); // doesn't work, WHY?
                    this.$el.html(html); // does work but it wraps it around a div
                    this.onDomRefresh();
                    return this;
                }

            }
        );
    }
);
```

template to be rendered:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
    <li><a href="/application/<%= appId %>/settings"><i class="icon-home"></i> Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now what i don't get is why it doesn't work when i remove the comment before el, then it doesn't show anything..

even when i try it with `$('#application-detail').html(html);` it doesn't show nothing. However `$('#application-detail')` returns the object correctly... So what is going on here?

I also tried passing {el : "#application-nav"} with the view, but this also doesn't work.

**It shows nothing.. However when i don't specify the el element, it works fine but it wraps it in a div.. which i don't want!**

I can't seem to find the problem and i'm clueless.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bakcbone by default creates a Div at the time to render your view, so If you dont want the div to be created change this default in your view, by setting the tagName property to the HTML element you need.

```
return Marionette.ItemView.extend
    (
        {
            template: tpl,
            tagName 'nav',
            className : 'yourCSSClass',

            initialize : function()
            { ........
```

Also the el you are specifying is the el of the region, inside your Layout, that is the conflict.

Comment: Yeah i know i could add a tagName and a className property, and in that case the problem is solved, but i thought that you could set the el property and that it adds the html to that element, isn't that correct? And the HTML to be rendered is just a ul element, i've added it

Comment: I think your approach would work in other scenarions ( setting the el inside the view but in this case the conflict is the you are using the same el of the region.change the el of the region a level up, in the view use the tagName to be a nav element.

Comment: but that is what i want: add my rendered templated to the element which is a region. Isn't that possible than?

Comment: if you do that, and you close the view, the el will be removed, and you wont be able to show another view in that region as  the el is no longer in the DOM.

Comment: Oh.. I don't want that of course. Hmm ok, can you edit your answer to add a tagName and a className, which is the solution in this case i guess.. and i will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do here is use a loyout with regions and render your item view inside a region by `region.show(myViewInstance);`